# Measurable Function mapping Binary Strings to the Unit Interval

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega:=\{0,1\}^\infty$ be the set of infinite binary sequences, let $b:=(b_1b_2\cdots)\in\Omega$ be such a sequence, and let $b^n:=(b_1b_2\cdots b_n)$. Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},P)$ be a probability space with $\mathfrak{A}$ the Borel field generated by the cylinder sets $S(b^n):=\{w\in\Omega{:}\ w_1=b_1,\dots,w_n=b_n\}$ and $P$ a probability measure satisfying $P(S(b^n))=1/2^n$.

Let $[0,1]$ be the unit interval and let $\mathfrak{B}_{[0,1]}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$. Define $f{:}\ (\Omega,\mathfrak{A})\to ([0,1],\mathfrak{B}_{[0,1]})$ as
\begin{equation}
 f(b):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{2^n}
\end{equation}

It is known that $f$ is measurable and surjective. I would like to show that $f$ is also bimeasurable, i.e., that

$$
 \forall A\in\mathfrak{A}{:}\ f(A)\in\mathfrak{B}_{[0,1]}.
$$

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found on this [blog](http://pjampana.blogspot.co.at/2014/10/borel-sets-of-infinite-binary-sequences.html), and in the proof of Theorem 2.1 in Parthasarathy's "Probability measures on metric spaces".